# how to add WiFi network adapter to a virtual Windows 10 on VMware player

Tags: windows, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

We are developing a .NET app on Windows 10 that must communicate with our Linux app.
Linux runs VMware which virtualizes Windows 10.

But we can't find a VMware selection for WiFi.

Using VirtualBox, virtual Windows 10 WiFi works OK.
But we need to use VMware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to connect the VM to the internet choose a "NAT" network adapter type or a "Bridged" network adapter if you need your VM to appear on the same network as other machines :) If you require the VM to have WIFI specifically, you'll need to add an external WIFI dongle/card and pass it to the VM...